# Installing Pow 0.4.1 on OS X Mountain Lion: Illegal Instruction 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

First post here.

I have POW version 0.3.2 installed and working seamlessly, which it has been for a long time. For the first time I have the need of accessing my POW virtual hosts from another machine on the network (an iPad), which requires POW version 0.4.0 or higher. When I try to install (upgrade) PO using `curl get.pow.cx | sh` it starts the installation but eventually comes back with an error like so:

`*** Installing Pow 0.4.1...

*** Installing local configuration files...

sh: line 95:  3513 Illegal instruction: 4  "$NODE_BIN" "$POW_BIN" --install-local`

I have the latest Xcode installed with the command line tools; I have node.js installed via the packaged installer, originally it was v. 0.8.21, but in trying to get this fixed I installed the latest version; As mentioned in the title I have OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.4). Please let me know if more info is needed. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I did not solve the above issue of installing pow with the install script, but I did manage to install it the [manual way](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Installation), which is a huge pain. For some reason I had to install each dependancy manually too, which added to my pain. Hope this "helps" someone else ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on OS X Lion. I haven't figured out what is wrong, so I used Homebrew. First, install Homebrew if you didn't:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Than run:

```
$ brew install pow
```

And follow these instructions:

```
$ sudo pow --install-system
$ pow --install-local
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/cx.pow.firewall.plist
$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/cx.pow.powd.plist
```

Also, you always can install Pow from source.

Comment: You rock! I ran into the same issue, and this worked perfectly.